# Appcelerator Error while reading asset bootstrap.js

Tags: appcelerator, appcelerator-titanium, appcelerator-studio

I am facing below error while running app using ti 7.0.2 sdk.

TiAssetHelper: Error while reading asset "ResourcesAPI/bootstrap.js":
[ERROR] :  TiAssetHelper: java.io.FileNotFoundException: ResourcesAPI/bootstrap.js
[ERROR] :  TiAssetHelper:   at android.content.res.AssetManager.openAsset(Native Method)
[ERROR] :  TiAssetHelper:   at android.content.res.AssetManager.open(AssetManager.java:347)
[ERROR] :  TiAssetHelper:   at android.content.res.AssetManager.open(AssetManager.java:321)
[ERROR] :  TiAssetHelper:   at org.appcelerator.kroll.util.KrollAssetHelper.readAsset(KrollAssetHelper.java:61)
[ERROR] :  TiAssetHelper:   at org.appcelerator.kroll.runtime.v8.V8Object.nativeCallProperty(Native Method)
[ERROR] :  TiAssetHelper:   at org.appcelerator.kroll.runtime.v8.V8Object.callProperty(V8Object.java:73)
[ERROR] :  TiAssetHelper:   at org.appcelerator.kroll.KrollProxy.handleMessage(KrollProxy.java:1173)
[ERROR] :  TiAssetHelper:   at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:98)
[ERROR] :  TiAssetHelper:   at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:154)
[ERROR] :  TiAssetHelper:   at org.appcelerator.kroll.KrollRuntime$KrollRuntimeThread.run(KrollRuntime.java:118)

Please suggest.I have checked modules folder and it doesnt have bootstrap.js file.Error continued after copying bootstrap.js file from older module version.